# Child thread synchronization is not working here

Tags: java

Java Code:

```
// Create a second thread.
class NewThread implements Runnable 
{
    Thread t;
    NewThread() 
    {   
        t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");    // Create a new, second thread
        System.out.println("Child thread: " + t);
        t.start();              // Start the thread
    }
    public void run()   // This is the entry point for the second thread.
    {
        justCall();
    }
    public synchronized void justCall()
    {
        try 
        {   
                for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    System.out.println("Child Thread: " + i);
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                }

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Child interrupted.");
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting child thread.");
    }
}
class ThreadDemo 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        NewThread nt = new NewThread();         // create a new thread
        try 
        {
            for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) 
            {
                System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
        }   
        System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
    }
}
```

here you can delete the synchronized justCall() method and you can initialize a synchronization block in a run() method(put justCall() method's code in a synchronized block).

How to synchronize child code here? Please Help. I read that Thread.sleep() method never releases the lock while it is executing in the synchronization block or method. But in  my code main thread and child code executes concurrently. Please help  to synchronize the child code using Thread.sleep() method.

Answer (score 2):

When two threads synchronize on the same object, they will not both run that same code. This allows many different threads to cooperate running in many different areas of code at the same time.

A `synchronized` on a non-static method creates a lock on the `this` object. If it had been a static method the lock would have been on the `Class` object for the `NewThread` class. Any class and any instance of any class can have a `syncronized` on it and thus create a lock.

You have only one thread running in the synchronized area. So, while it is locked, no other thread is attempting to run the locked code. No other thread is attempting to synchronize on the `nt` instance of the `NewThread` class.

You might want to try doing this:

```
NewThread nt1 = new NewThread();         // create a new thread
NewThread nt2 = new NewThread();         // create a 2nd new thread
```

Then leave off the looping in the main class.